# Dynamically changing a cell's height that contains a collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a table view with various cells. They are all set to resize using

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 45.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

For example if the cell is a label type and the label contains multiple lines of text, the label will expand and cause the cells height to increase. I have just created a new type of cell with a collection view inside it. It works great however the problem is that when more cells are added the collection view it's frame doesn't grow in size and thus the cell's height doesn't expand. Instead the collection view just becomes scrollable. Is there a way to make the collection view frame expand as more cells are added instead of making it scrollable? Any pointers on this would be really appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set a constraint to the collection view and then resize it by code.

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!


 let height = cells.count * a  //a = height of the cells within the collection view
 collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = CGFloat(height)
```